# Drag and Drop jQuery Save Position to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

I know how to get the position of draggable div using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#q").draggable();
    $("#bt").click(function(){
        alert("LEFT: "+$("#q").offset().left+" TOP: "+$("#q").offset().top);
    })
})
```

But my problem is that if I insert the LEFT and TOP position of the div on the database and I open the webpage on another computer with different monitor resolution the div is missed aligned..

Is there an way that I can do fix this

THANKS !!

Comment: If it is somewhere different, it sounds like you're using a percentage based layout (fluid) - in which case you should probably do a little bit of maths and get the width of the screen to work out where it should be as a percentage of the width

Comment: can I do that using javascript? jquery?

Comment: `$(window).width();` - will give you the browser viewpoint width ... then simply divide `$("#q").offset().left` by this width to get the percentage (out of 1)

Comment: windows sizes will differ with monitor resolutions. draggable works with fixed positioning so even if you store it in db, in other monitors it looks different. best method is to take the window with and then take the percentage to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could make a perportion so that it is a percent top/left from one screen, and then if another monitor is a different size, it will still be in the "same spot."

Something like

```
var ntop = $("#q").offset().left / $("#q").width();
var nleft = $("#q").offset().top / $("#q").height();
```

And to use it

```
$("#q").offset({"left": nleft, "top": ntop});
```

You will need to save the variables using ajax or similar, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#q").draggable();
    $("#bt").click(function(){
        alert("LEFT: "+$("#q").offset().left+" TOP: "+$("#q").offset().top);
        $.get("test.cgi", { left: nleft, top: ntop });
    });
});
```

Of course, I won't build it for you, but hopefully the above will help.

Comment: YES SIR! Thanks! :D I'll try it